# Cannot get the length of an array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am fetching a list of **orders** in my React/Redux app. The user types a word into the "Search" component and a list of orders should display below in the "List" component. From inside of the "List" component I console.log(orders), it returns an empty array (i default the state to be an empty array) when I submit a search term it returns an array with 5 items.

```
[] 
orders: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

However, if I console.log(orders.length) i get '0' but once I submit a search it returns undefined. Why? Is it not an array?

```
[]
0
{orders: Array(5)}
undefined
```

List Component:

```
export class List extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { orders } = this.props;
    console.log(orders.orders);

    return <div>List Component</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  orders: state.orders.ordersArr
});
```

Reducer:

```
  const initialState = {
     name: '',
     ordersArr: []
  };
  export default (state = initialState, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_ORDERS':
          return { ...state, ordersArr: action.payload };
```

Reducers Index

```
export default combineReducers({
  orders: ordersReducer
});
```

Action:

```
export const fetchOrders = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await work.get(`/needtoorders`);

  dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ORDERS', payload: response.data });
};
```

Comment: can you share some code ?

Comment: if it's not an array then what is it? can you verify what exactly is being returned from your reducer. `response.data` might not be an array @j_nguyen

Comment: @VahidAkhtar

`console.log(Array.isArray(orders.orders)); // true`
`console.log(state)`
orders:
name: "a"
ordersArr:
orders: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: @hussain.codes console.log(Array.isArray(orders.orders)); // true

Comment: okay, i think your state data type is not consistent, it's changing. for example initially `orders.orders` is an array (you have set it in reducer) but when user types something it's changing from an array to something else, you need to check what and why exactly this happening, i would suggest you to check what are you dispatching from your action.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `orders` is an object, consisting of a property called `orders` as well. And that property consists on an array.

Try this instead:

```
console.log(orders.orders.length)
```

Given that `orders` and `orders.orders` might be undefined, you may try this too.

```
if (orders && orders.orders && orders.orders.length > 0) {
  console.log(orders.orders.length)
}
```

Comment: `console.log(orders.orders);` 
returns (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
`console.log(orders.orders.length)` throws an error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @j_nguyen I have updated my code. Do take a look at the optional/undefined check on the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `initialState` containing `ordersArr` not contains `orders`

Comment: i failed to mention I passed reducers to combinedReducers and passed them as props called 'orders'

Comment: yes, he is assigning ordersArr to orders, so it's not a issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
if (orders && orders.orders && orders.orders.length > 0) {
  console.log(orders.orders.length)
}
```

Hope it helps